# PHP Verification system in form submission

Tags: php, html

I want to link the data sent from the html form to update.php to a permission system, for example, the data coming out of the form must first reach admin-control.php and then update.php, and at the same time ask the user for username and password on the website. I tried to do this and compiled the following lines of code, but I still don't know how to connect them each other. I am waiting for your help, my valuable teachers.

Note: I am aware of my old usage (mysql) of the PHP language and I will fix it soon, but right now that's okay for me.

Best regards,
Efe Cetinkaya

**Panel.php:**

```
                                <div class="info-box">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>İçerik Başlığı</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title"/>
                                   </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Açıklama</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"/>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Kategori</label>
                                    <div><label>Seçili Kategoriler : </label><label id="current_categoies"></label></div>
                                    <div id="select2">
                                      <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Kategori Seç" style="width: 100%;" id="category" name="category[]">
                                      

                                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                   
                                  <input type="hidden" id="video_id" name="video_id"/>
                                  <input type="submit" value="Güncelle" class="btn btn-primary" id="update"/>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**admin-verification.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$errorMsg = "";
$validUser = $_SESSION["login"] === true;
if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
  $validUser = $_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == "12345678Abc";
  if(!$validUser) $errorMsg = "Yanlış kullanıcı adı veya şifre!";
  else $_SESSION["login"] = true;
}
if($validUser) {
   header("Location: /update.php"); die();
}
?>
```

**update.php:**

```
<?php
    
    include("db/db.php");

    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $video_id= $_POST["video_id"];

    $update_details=mysql_query("update videos set title='$title', description='$description' where video_id=$video_id");
    if(isset($_POST['category']))
    {
        
        foreach ($_POST['category'] as $selectedCategory)
        {
        
            $update_category=mysql_query("insert into vid_cat values(null,$video_id,$selectedCategory)");
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['new_category']))
    {
         $insert_new=mysql_query("insert into categories value(null,'$_POST[new_category]')");
      
        
        if(mysql_affected_rows()==1)
        {
            $category_id= mysql_insert_id();
            $update_category=mysql_query("insert into vid_cat values(null,$video_id,$category_id)");

        }
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["success"]=1;
    header("location:manage.php");

    
?>
```

Comment: use ajax call to update.php file pass every POST value

Comment: Can you give an example or can you apply and write your change that you mentioned on the pages I discarded?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In admin-verification.php file, your password validation is not met the standards, go through the basics process by searching google or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544250/php-password-validation).
apart form this to take post values to another files you can use ajax call, check below

```
<?php
if($validUser) {?>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var title       =   '<?php echo $_POST["title"]; ?>';
    var description =   '<?php echo $_POST["description"]; ?>';
    var video_id    =   '<?php echo $_POST["video_id"]; ?>';
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/update.php",
        data: {title: title, description: description, video_id: video_id}
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Okay, I will try and reply to you, thank you very much for your comment and your time :)